# Unable to implement the Recycler view Adaptor in fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, fragment

I am not able to attach the Firestore Recycler Adapter in the fragment.
I googled many things but no good yet.
The fragment is one of the tabs of the bottomtablayout.
The data is retrieved from a single collection. I want represent the list of multlipe-user post in a single view.

I have tried the below code but to no good yet.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(c);

        Query query = PostsRef.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostsModel>()
                .setQuery(query, PostsModel.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(options);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(c));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

         mParent =view.findViewById(R.id.relative_home);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);


    }
```

Adapter Code

```
public class PostsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PostsModel, PostsAdapter.PostsHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public PostsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PostsModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PostsModel model) {
        //retrieve the fields here
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getPostTitle());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getPostContent());
        holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(model.getSpinnerC()));
        holder.AuthorName.setText(model.getName());
        holder.AuthorGender.setText(model.getGender());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_list_layout,
                parent, false);
        return new PostsHolder(v);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

    class PostsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        TextView textViewPriority;
        TextView AuthorName;
        TextView AuthorGender;

        public PostsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quote1);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name1);
            textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp1);

                    }
    }

  }
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Do you have an error?

Comment: no error shows up, but when I run the code recyclerview doesn't show up in the fragment there is no list updated from the database to the screen

Comment: Have you tried to remove  `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`?

Comment: thanks alot Alex, it helped me a lot

Comment: how can I do something to upvote your help?

Comment: You should wait to earn some reputation and then you'll be able :)

Answer (score 0):

You're inflating the other view in the onCreateView method.

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
```

Comment: if i remove this statement it asks me for a return statement, what should I write code for the return statement? and recyclerview is configured in the fragment_home layout